# How to compare a date when the date is stored as a varchar

Tags: mysql

The dates in my database are stored as varchars instead of date formats due to the way it was first built.

The dates look like this:
e.g. **1/3/2015** and
**10/3/2015**

I'm trying:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) n FROM tracker WHERE TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y'))<=NOW()"
```

However, that's not working. It is returning the count of all records, regardless of the date.

How can I count only the records where the date is today or in the past?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `TIMESTAMP()`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as n
FROM tracker
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') <= NOW()
```

Comment: That still returns the count of all records. I checked NOW() and it also returns the time... so I tried replacing it with date_format(curdate(), '%d/%m/%Y') but then it returns 0.

Comment: Perhaps all records are in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention to the functions STR_TO_DATE and NOW(), the first return a date, the second is a timestamp.
When you convert STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') you will get a date with hours, minutes and seconds as 00:00:00

Using CURRENT_DATE perhaps will match more closely the original requirements

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as n 
FROM tracker
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') <= CURRENT_DATE
```

Also I suggest you to rename the column 'date'